# Running PR2 in Gazebo; 2dnav gives TF errors

Tags: gazebo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to test some software I wrote in simulation before running it on the real PR2. I created a little Gazebo world that is a somewhat accurate representation of my workspace, and I launch it and it works fine for the most part. I can launch `pr2_2dnav_slam.launch` and teleop the simulated PR2 around to generate a map of the area. Then I save the map, and I want to load it as a static map using a `map_server` and then launch the nav stack. However, at this point the nav stack starts throwing a bunch of TF errors that all basically look like

> [ERROR] [1327451804.285384190,
> 15.638000000]: Transform unavailable Lookup would require extrapolation
> into the past.  Requested time
> 15.288000000 but the earliest data is at time 15.508000000, when looking up
> transform from frame [/base_footprint]
> to frame [/base_link]

and becomes basically unusable. I have set ROBOT=sim and I'm using https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/wg_robots_gazebo/trunk/pr2_2dnav_gazebo/2dnav-stack-amcl.launch to launch the nav stack which should ensure that it's using the simulated PR2.

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12743/running-pr2-in-gazebo;-2dnav-gives-tf-errors/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2012-01-25**:
Oh thanks! Starting everything together makes it work. I'm guessing I didn't set use_sim_time properly for the other nodes?

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2012-01-25**:
I didn't try that one, I'll try it out now. For me I get the errors only at the beginning but then I can't actually do anything with the nav stack at that point (eg. I tried publishing an initial pose to localize, didn't work, etc).

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-01-24**:
I do see the same error a couple times on startup, but the error stops and things work correctly.  Do you see a continuous stream of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try the launch file: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/wg_robots_gazebo/trunk/pr2_2dnav_gazebo/pr2-empty-amcl.launch for starting everything together?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0